# How to find words without certain letters in them and certain letters in the same place that are in specified length

Tags: python

I want to make a hangman game that randomises the word each time you guess a letter, but keeps the wrong letters wrong and the ones you guessed at the same place in the new word. (Like if your word was `cat` in the beginning and you guessed the 'a'; now the word can be `hat`.)
I feel like I want to implement too many statements in a `while` loop and it breaks somehow.

I have this function

```
def RevealLetters(inputLetter):
    LetterPositons.clear()
    global WrongGuessCounter
    for pos,char in enumerate(Word):
        if(char == inputLetter):
            LetterPositons.append(pos)   

    for x in LetterPositons:
        if MaskedWord[x] == "_":
            MaskedWord[x] = inputLetter

    if len(LetterPositons) == 0:
        WrongGuessCounter += 1
        WrongLetters.append(inputLetter)
```

Which adds the wrongly guessed letter to a list and those letters should not be used again.
Then in another function I have this `while` loop which should be able to go thru the list of words and select words that are a specified length (the length was set in another function)

```
def RandomiseWord():
    global Word
    print("Randomising Word!")
    Word = random.choice(WordBank)
    LetterPositons.clear()
        
    while (len(Word) != len(MaskedWord)) and (all(letter in Word for letter in WrongLetters)) :
        Word = random.choice(WordBank)
```

but this somehow gives me words that either contain a letter from the list or a word with a  different length.

I tried using `if` statements inside the `while` but it broke it further.

And lastly how may I check for words that have the same letters in the same place?

Comment: At least in `RandomiseWord()` there is a semicolon in the `while` statement before `&` that you should remove

Comment: That's a colon, not a semicolon. `&` should almost certainly be `and`

Comment: Thanks. That was left there while i was testing some stuff

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my while. it has to be the "Or" statement.
in the end the randomise function looked like this:
def RandomiseWord(): #Randomises the word to add a challange to the game

```
global Word
global MaskedWord
global WrongLetters
print("Randomising Word!")
Word = random.choice(WordBank)
LetterPositons.clear()
    
while len(Word) != (len(MaskedWord)+1) or all(letter in Word for letter in WrongLetters) or not all(CheckWord()) :
    Word = random.choice(WordBank)
```

and for finding words with letters in the same place I used:

```
def CheckWord(): #checks if the word contains the letters in the same place as the hidden one
    global MaskedWord
    global Word
    Match = []
    LetterList = list(Word)
    LetterList.pop()
    for x in range(len(MaskedWord)):
        if MaskedWord[x] == "_":
            continue
        elif MaskedWord[x] == LetterList[x]:
            Match.append(True)
        else:
            Match.append(False)
    return Match
```